# Ruby - Function callable from within class only and copy from outside class only

Tags: ruby

I am not sure what the best way to describe this is so I'm not sure if this is already answered somewhere. Apologies if it is.

This is an example of what I'd like to do.

```
class Foo
    def run
        bar
    end

    # Only callable from within this class
    def bar
        puts "A"
    end

    # Only callable from outside this class
    def bar
        puts "B"
    end
end

obj = Foo.new
obj.run # 'A'
obj.bar # 'B'
```

The obvious answer is this, but I'd rather avoid trusting people to get the parameter correct.

```
class Foo
    def run
        bar(true)
    end

    def bar(param)
        if param
            puts "A"
        else
            puts "B"
        end
    end
end

obj = Foo.new
obj.run # 'A'
obj.bar(false) # 'B'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have 2 methods with the same name (the second will just overwrite the first). General convention for this type of thing would be to call one method `_bar` (the underscore is used to "visually" represent the method as private), this is usually accompanied by making the method private as well. Please be aware this does not prohibit calling the method from the outside it just puts up a little fence. Now if your intent is for `run` to serve both purposes, e.g. `run` inside the class returns "A" and outside returns "B", then I would rethink your design.

Comment: Sounds more like an XY problem (and violation of LSP, too, but first things first :)). Could you please describe _the problem_ you are trying to solve this way?